# How can I get the to-address of a transaction from a transaction hash in Solana

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-transaction-instruction

I'm trying to get all the information like from-address, to-address, amount, etc in my JS backend to confirm a transaction using it's hash. The transaction object returned from the getTransaction RPC call has a array for owner account PublicKey(from-address) but can't find a way to find the to-address. How can I find this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the [CompiledInstructions](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#CompiledInstruction) (found on TransactionResponse.transaction.message.instructions) and decode them one by one.

Regular SOL transfers would be transfer instructions called on the system program. [Web3.js has a helper for that purpose](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/web3.js/src/system-program.ts#L249).

SPL Transfers would be transfer instructions called on the token program. I something similar for the initialcapoffering.com order form, [this code might be helpful](https://gist.github.com/mschneider/14f8c1c969b1d6a37c824255a87f36a3)